# How to make react-typescript className to array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

So say I have a component with single reference to styles, works well

```
export const something = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.myStyle}
  )
}:
```

But say, I want to have a reference with multiple styles like

```
export const something = () => {
  return (
    <div className={[styles.myStyle, styles.myOtherStyle]}
  )
}:
```

Typescript throws an `error` says:

> The expected type comes from property 'className' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Readonly> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

How would I change the `className` type to array to be able to accept the format I want?

Comment: To be clear, react `className` prop accepts only string as input, any  value of other type pass to it will be implicitly converted to string by calling `String(value)`. An array of `['foo', 'bar']` will be `"foo,bar"` after conversion. So first of all, is this your expected behavior?

Comment: @hackape No? I wanted `className` to be able to accept multiple sets of values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type of `className` is `String` and you are passing type `Array<String>`

`className={[styles.myStyle, styles.myOtherStyle]}`

Which is not assignable.

So either you have to make that array into a string using `join()` or `concatenation` or use a [classnames library](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)

- `[styles.myStyle, styles.myOtherStyle].join(' ')`
- `{styles.myStyle + ' ' + styles.myOtherStyle}`
- ${styles.myStyle}`${styles.myOtherStyle}`

**using classnames library**

```
import * as classnames from 'classnames'
className={classnames(styles.myStyle, styles.myOtherStyle)}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
className={[styles.myStyle, styles.myOtherStyle, "otherClass"].join(' ')}

className={`${styles.foo} ${styles.bar}`}
```

Comment: that sure works but It's messy, is there a way I can declare the type from string to array?

Comment: backticks are cleaner i guess

Comment: it says my rep is lower than 15 so it is not publicly viewed, but was recorded. they said.

Answer (score 0):

`className` of react component only accept value of `string` type.
Since `[styles.myStyle, styles.myOtherStyle]` is value of `Array<string>`, you got the type-check error.You can tranform the arry to string using `join` by yourself or use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) as below to get more features :

```
<div className={classnames([styles.myStyle, styles.myOtherStyle])} />
```

Comment: will check it out, will use backticks for the meantime thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) could be leveraged:

```
import * as classnames from 'classnames'
className={classnames(styles.foo, styles.bar)}
```

It enables very different use-cases, see [usage](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#usage).

For typescript, types are also available:

```
npm i -D @types/classnames
```

This adds another dependency which is better to prevent if not absolutely needed. Alex's answer (template string or your wrapper) should be the default.

```
const className = (...classes) => classes.map((e) => String(e)).filter((e) => e).join(" ")
```